# Load and adapt Report from a jasper file instead JRXML file

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

my way, using JasperReports in Java is:

- Load JRXML
- Setup Query
- Setup some Options (locale, etc...)
- Compile Report
- Export Report (PDF, XLS,....)

Is there any way to do it like this ?

- Load Jasper File (XXX.jasper)
- Setup Query
- Setup some Options (locale, etc...)
- Export Report (PDF, XLS,....)

So I can save some seconds for the the Compiling time.

Any ideas ?
thx

Comment: Yes, this is common. It's shown in many of the samples that ship with JasperReports. Have you played with the included samples yet?

Comment: This will not work the way you are expecting. You will not be able to change/setup the query of the compiled report (i.e. JasperReport object). You will have to convert it to a JasperDesign object, which then means it will have to be recompiled again before export.

Comment: Hi. It is a little bit confusing. First people says: Yes it is the common way. Another people says. No it is not possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such way. Don't load `JRXML` into `JasperDesign`, which will compile into `JasperReport`, but load directly `JasperReport`.